# How to call script B from script A as if script B is in script A's location

Tags: bash, scripts

To the detail,script B is at a location different from that of script A. Script B will also call other scripts. If I call script B from script A, bash will report the scripts called by script B do not exist. How do I fix this?

Sorry for the confusion. It's my fault. I will rewrite the question as follow:

The file system hierarchy are:

```
> $HOME
>     Script A
>     Folder2
>         Script B
>         Script C
>         Script D
>         ....
```

The script C and D are called by B, if I call script B from script A by `./Folder2/B`, errors are reported that C and D don't exist.

To the questions:

1. I use Ubuntu 20.04
2. Has nothing to do with absolute path, I changed the calling in script A to `$HOME/Folder2/B` and `/home/myName/Folder2/B`, the result remains the same.
3. No, all are not in my $PATH
4. SHEBANG: #!/bin/bash
5. No, they are where they should be and static.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1412315/edit) and add the scripts and respective locations.

Comment: See https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix/ . Look at the sections regarding *absolute paths*.

Comment: A lot more clarity is needed. How are the scripts calling other scripts? WIth `source scriptname` (`.`), or with `bash scriptname.sh`, or with just `scriptname.sh`? Are the scripts called from A executable and do they have shebangs? Are they in your `$PATH`? Can you predict the location of the scripts ahead of time? Can you navigate to the folder of script A in script B before calling script A?

Comment: Why does script location matter? Scripts should use absolute paths, and not be depending on where they are located.

Comment: @frabjous Hi I have edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Absolute or not, the problem remains the same.

Comment: @karel No, but thanks.

Comment: @ user535733 Absolute or not, the problem remains the same.

Comment: @Ciriously If you don't put them in your `$PATH`, then either *all* the paths need to be  relative to the path the script is executing in (which you can change with cd inside the script), *not* relative to the path the scripts are located in, or they must be absolute. If you want to use absolute paths, you need to make the paths to C and D inside B absolute as well, not just the path to B inside A. Another option is to put `cd $HOME/Folder2` inside the script before executing B from A (then simply as `./B`), and then the paths to C and D inside B can be relative to B.

Comment: You should include the script code where you call the scripts, and also error messages you get. This is still purely guessing from our side.

Comment: @Ciriously You went "silent" on us here after I provided an answer based on my understanding of your question (although I notice you've visited the site since then several times).  Did my answer cover your use-case?  If so, then please accept it so that we can close this out.  If it did not, then I agree with the other comments here -- You really should edit the question to include enough sample code for us to understand your question, reproduce it, and help us help you.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Sorry, I am very busy right now, and will check this out about one week later.

Comment: @Ciriously Sounds good - Thanks for the reply and checking in!

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding you, or perhaps your title doesn't quite match the question.

It sounds like you have something like:

`$HOME/script1`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo In $0
./Folder2/script2
```

`$HOME/Folder2/script2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo In $0
./script3
```

`$HOME/Folder2/script3`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo In $0
```

Executing:

```
> $HOME/script1

In /home/username/script1
In ./Folder2/script2
./Folder2/script2: line 3: ./script3: No such file or directory
```

In that case, the title of your question is really what *is* happening.  The working directory of `script2` really *is* the same as that of `script1` (`$HOME`), which means that `script3` isn't found in the working directory by `script2`.

What it *sounds* like you want is for `script2` to always operate as if it is in `Folder2`, so that it will find the other scripts that are in the same directory.

If that's the case, then you *could* do it by simply changing the directory in `script2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo In $0
cd "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"
./script3.sh
```

But probably better and cleaner would be to store the directory in a variable and use it to call the scripts with absolute paths:

`script2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo In $0
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"
$SCRIPT_DIR/script3
```